# Can "Match Mode" functionality be created within a LAMBDA function in Excel?

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I'm just starting to play around with `LAMBDA`, and was wondering if it was possible to replicate the mode selection that a few formulas have. For instance when using `XLOOKUP`:

["Match Mode" example within XLOOKUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqeeK.png)

Can you create these option drop downs within `LAMBDA`? An `IF` statement could be used to point to different calculations based on a 0, -1 or 1, but a user would need to know that those specific inputs mean.

I created a lambda that normalizes a selected array by column to help with linearly rescaling data, but thought it would be a great addition to allow users to pick if the array should be normalized by column, row, or the entire array.

Here's what I have so far if anyone is interested. Would the best way be to create 3 separate formulas .col .row and .all (or something)?

```
NORMALIZE.COL =
LAMBDA(
    array,
LET(
    rng, array,
    col, COLUMN(rng),
    rows, ROWS(rng),
    min,SUBTOTAL(5,OFFSET(INDEX(rng,1,1),,col-MIN(col),rows)),
    max,SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX(rng,1,1),,col-MIN(col),rows)),
    (rng-min)/(max-min)
    )
);
```

Comment: Is this one question (re `MATCH`) or two (the first re `MATCH` and the second re your normalizing function)? You should make clear your intended connection between the two. Re `MATCH`, something like `=LAMBDA(match_mode,MATCH("x",Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10,match_mode))` with, for example, `A1`, `A3` and `A6` containing "a", "x" and "x" respectively, would return: `MyMatch(0)=3`, `MyMatch(1)=6` and `MyMatch(-1)=#N/A`.

Comment: Hi, my question was more about the drop-down feature that some functions use like XLOOKUP and its "match mode" option . I'm not sure if there is an official name. But it looks like this is not built in yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is not a way of showing drop-down options (like your XLOOKUP example) for a LAMBDA parameter when entering the formula.

I think the best you can do is to give the parameter a meaningful name like Col_Row_Array - this will be shown at formula entry